# Rails validation and 'fieldWithErrors' wrapping select tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, actionview, field-with-errors

Is it normal behaviour to not get the `<div class="fieldWithErrors">` wrapped arround select tags that have validation errors? I personally see no reason why the select tags should be treated differently than other form tags (input, textarea).

I *do* get the error in `error_messages_for` and `error_message_on` methods for that field.

PS. I have altered a bit the `ActionView::Base.field_error_proc` in order to get span tags instead of divs, but that isn't the problem.

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new { |html_tag, instance|
   #if I puts html_tag here I only get the <input> tags
   "<span class=\"fieldWithErrors\">#{html_tag}</span>"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because I couldn't find out why the select tags were not included in that Proc, I created a helper method which does preety much the same thing.

```
def field_with_error(object, method, &block)
  if block_given?
    if error_message_on(object, method).empty?
      concat capture(&block)
    else
      concat '<span class="fieldWithErrors">' + capture(&block) + '</span>'
    end
  end
end
```

I use it in my views like so:

```
<% field_with_error @some_object, :assoc do %>
  <%= f.select(:assoc_id, @associations.collect {|assoc| [ asoc.name, assoc.id ] }) %>
<% end %>
```

If anybody knows a better or cleaner way to do it, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

The problem (for me at least) was that my `f.select :whatever_id` was looking in the `object.errors` object for a key of `:whatever_id` when my validation was actually on `:whatever`, not `:whatever_id`.

I worked around this annoying problem by changing

```
object.errors.on(@method_name)
```

to

```
object.errors.on(@method_name) || object.errors.on(@method_name.gsub(/_id$/, ''))
```

Here's the diff (against Rails 2.3.4):

```
diff --git a/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/active_record_helper.rb b/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/active_record_helper.rb
index 541899e..5d5b27e 100644
--- a/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/active_record_helper.rb
+++ b/vendor/rails/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/active_record_helper.rb
@@ -247,7 +247,7 @@ module ActionView
       alias_method :tag_without_error_wrapping, :tag
       def tag(name, options)
         if object.respond_to?(:errors) && object.errors.respond_to?(:on)
-          error_wrapping(tag_without_error_wrapping(name, options), object.errors.on(@method_name))
+          error_wrapping(tag_without_error_wrapping(name, options), object.errors.on(@method_name) || object.errors.on(@method_name.gsub(/_id$/, '')))
         else
           tag_without_error_wrapping(name, options)
         end
@@ -256,7 +256,7 @@ module ActionView
       alias_method :content_tag_without_error_wrapping, :content_tag
       def content_tag(name, value, options)
         if object.respond_to?(:errors) && object.errors.respond_to?(:on)
-          error_wrapping(content_tag_without_error_wrapping(name, value, options), object.errors.on(@method_name))
+          error_wrapping(content_tag_without_error_wrapping(name, value, options), object.errors.on(@method_name) || object.errors.on(@method_name.gsub(/_id$/, '')))
         else
           content_tag_without_error_wrapping(name, value, options)
         end
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this blog post which appears to address this:

http://blog.invalidobject.com/2007/09/16/rails-error-wrapping-for-select-input-fields-of-referenced-models

Hope it is helpful!

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the reply! I found that too, but he doesn't really specify if and how he got it working. There is one link to the rails wiki, but it is broken. I would like to avoid as much as possible adding a test on 'error_message_on' for every select because that would really complicate my views.

Comment: He does specify how to get it work here : "The only solution is to change the validation in the working_time model from project to project_id". That is, in the model class, change "validates_presence_of :project" to "validates_presence_of :project_id"

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I solve that problem.

I create an specific "field_with_errors" select wrapper:

```
ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = Proc.new do |html_tag, instance|
   if html_tag =~ /^<input/
     %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}<label for="#{instance.send(:tag_id)}" class="message">#{instance.error_message.first}</label></div>}.html_safe
   elsif html_tag =~ /^<select/
 %{<div class="field_with_errors" id="select-error">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe
   else
     %{<div class="field_with_errors">#{html_tag}</div>}.html_safe
   end
end
```

The CSS:

```
#select-error {
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

And I modify my validations to :whatever_id instead of *:whatever*

```
validates :whatever_id, :presence => true
```

I was forgetting, the select:

```
f.collection_select(:whatever_id, Whatever.all, :id, :name, prompt: t(:please_choose))
```

Comment: Thanks, I found it handy to modify the if to include a check for a 'no-errors' class in the html_tag, when found don't display any errors at all. Very handy when some form fields have things like javascript datepickers on them which extra markup would break.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, can be inserted at method or controller level, or in the environment.rb:

ActionView::Base.field_error_proc = proc { |input, instance| input }